# Writing in a csv file the dataset obtained in Python

Tags: python

I have filtered a dataset in Python, from 4067642 items to 54 items. And now I need only to work with that subset in Excel, or R, since it was not possible working with the original dataset for the massive dimension. What I have to do is just exporting from Python environment my subdataset, writing it on csv file.

I never used Python before, could you suggest me which line should I write to run this command? I'm going to copy the all code, that is not too long, it is quite short, since the activity that I had to do was only to filter the data.

```
> import pandas as pd import numpy as np import csv import
> matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> 
> dir_file = "data/final_data/raw_data/" f_anac = dir_file +
> "anacDataset_1525953489668.csv"
> #df = pd.read_csv(f_anac, sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, parse_dates=True) df = pd.read_csv(f_anac, sep="\t", parse_dates=True,
> dtype= {"cfStrutturaProponente": str})
> 
> #ci sono typo in alcune date (e.g. 202/02/2016) df['dataInizio'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dataInizio'], errors='coerce', format="%d/%m/%Y")
> df['dataUltimazione'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dataUltimazione'],
> errors='coerce', format="%d/%m/%Y")
> 
> #pulisco i dati dalla string CDATA ed elimino spazi da i cf degli aggiudicatari df.oggetto = df.oggetto.apply(lambda x
> :str(x).lower().replace('cdata', ''))
> df.denominazionePrimoaggiudicatario =
> df.denominazionePrimoaggiudicatario.apply(lambda x
> :str(x).lower().replace('cdata', '')) df.cfPrimoaggiudicatario =
> df.cfPrimoaggiudicatario.str.replace(' ', '')
> 
> df.info()
> 
> is_Lamezia = (df['denominazioneStrutturaProponente'] == 'COMUNE DI
> LAMEZIA TERME') df_Lamezia = df.loc[is_Lamezia] print('Dimensione
> dataset originario', df.shape) print('Dimensione dataset filtrato',
> df_Lamezia.shape)
```

This is the structure of the dataset:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4067642 entries, 0 to 4067641
Data columns (total 17 columns):
cig                                  object
cfStrutturaProponente                object
denominazioneStrutturaProponente     object
oggetto                              object
sceltaContraente                     object
importoAggiudicazione                float64
importoSommeLiquidate                float64
dataInizio                           datetime64[ns]
dataUltimazione                      datetime64[ns]
jsonPartecipanti                     object
jsonAggiudicatari                    object
totalePartecipanti                   int64
totaleAggiudicatari                  int64
totaleRaggruppamentopartecipanti     int64
totaleRaggruppamentoAggiudicatari    int64
cfPrimoaggiudicatario                object
denominazionePrimoaggiudicatario     object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(2), int64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 527.6+ MB
```

I have tried to use `writer=csv.writer(df_Lamezia,dialect="excel")`, but it doesn't work. This is why I have not at all a knowledge of how to export data in csv in Python.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Pandas dataframe directly to an Excel file with this command:

```
df.to_excel('name.xlsx','name of the sheet')
```

or write to a csv file with

```
df.to_csv('csv_file.csv')
```

You can read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to see all other options to do it

Comment: I tried `df.to_csv('dfLamezia.csv')` but it is taking long time, even if they are only 54 rows and 17 columns. It is ordinary? So I have a doubt. From this command, does Python understand that I want to print only df_Lamezia and not all df?

Comment: Ok, I think to have understood: I should run df_Lamezia.to_csv('path')

Comment: So then you will need to do **df_Lamezia.to_csv('csv_file.csv')**

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to pass the entire data frame as a parameter to the `csv.writer()` method.

Instead, pass each row as a parameter to it.

```
import csv

with open('destination/location/file.csv', 'w') as fp:
    file_writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",")    
    for row in df.values:
        file_writer.writerow(row)
```

Edit: As mentioend by @nacho you can also use the `.to_csv` method.